# How to add an instance of a struct to a DynamicVector

Tags: mojolang

A total newbie question.

```
struct Item:
    var name: StringLiteral

    fn __init__(inout self):
        self.name = "Unnamed"

fn main():
    var dv = DynamicVector[Item]()
    var it = Item()
    dv.push_back(it)
```

Generates error: `invalid call to 'push_back': method argument #0 cannot bind generic !mlirtype to memory-only type 'Item'`

I don't understand the error message.

I cannot find in https://docs.modular.com/mojo/programming-manual.html the syntax for this.

Is there an equivalent to c++ vector::emplace(...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can only store types marked @register_passable in arrays. For example Int.

Comment: One would expect an error on the vector initialisation `var dv = DynamicVector[Item]()` in this case. What other data type should be used here?